Addresses and arrays in C
What is the difference (or link) between:

Case for 1D arrays:

Element address using pointers arr + i and
Element address = base address + element size * element number


Case for 2D arrays:

Address using pointers: (*(arr + i) + j) and
Element address = base address + element size * ((row number * total number of columns) + column number).



When should I use one or the other, or are they equivalent?

Element size is not used, because pointer arithmetic already works in units of elements and not bytes.

I'm not paying attention to all the formulas you wrote or trying to debug them.  I think on this site it really helps to discuss actual code.  If you have two ways of writing a program, just show the two ways as code.

They are only equivalent when the element size is 1. Pointer arithmetic takes the element size into account, in that same way that int arr[2]; arr[1] = 42; does.

For 1D arrays:

Element address using pointers:

This approach uses pointer arithmetic to calculate the address of the i-th element.
The base address of the array (arr) is a pointer, and adding i to it gives you the address of the i-th element.
This is a more direct and efficient way to access elements in a 1D array.


Element address = base address + element size * element number:

This approach calculates the address of the i-th element by taking the base address and adding the product of the element size and the element number (i).
This is a more explicit and verbose way to calculate the address, but it can be useful in some situations, such as when the element size is not fixed (e.g., in a struct array).



For 2D arrays:

Address using pointers: *(arr + i) + j:

This approach first calculates the address of the i-th row using pointer arithmetic (arr + i), and then adds the offset of the j-th column (+ j) to get the final address.
This is a more direct and efficient way to access elements in a 2D array.


Element address = base address + element size * ((row number * total number of columns) + column number):

This approach calculates the address of the element by taking the base address and adding the product of the element size, the row number, the total number of columns, and the column number.
This is a more explicit and verbose way to calculate the address, but it can be useful in some situations, such as when the element size is not fixed (e.g., in a struct array).



In general, the pointer-based approaches (arr + i and *(arr + i) + j) are more commonly used and efficient, as they directly leverage the underlying memory layout of the arrays. However, the explicit address calculation can be useful in certain scenarios, such as when working with variable-sized elements or when the array dimensions are not known at compile-time.

In an array all elements are of identical type, hence identical size. There is no " element size is not fixed" in an array in C.

For "Element address = base address + element size * element number:" what is the type of the expression that you are using for base address?

int a[ n ][ m ] has exactly the same size, alignment and layout as int a[ n * m ].
The only difference is that working with 2d data in 1d arrays isn't as clear.

The following is how you'd use a 1d array:
// Accepts a pointer to the first element of a 1d array.
void f1( size_t n, size_t m, int *p ) {
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
         size_t ij = i * m + j;
         printf( "%s%3d", j ? " " : "", p[ ij ] );
      }

      print( "\n" );
   }
}

int a1[ n * m ];
f1( n, m, a1 );
/* ---- or ---- */
int *p1 = malloc( sizeof( int ) * n * m );
f1( n, m, p1 );

Historically, this was the only option. Passing a 2d array of variable size to a function was impossible.
It is now possible, and it's far easier to read.
// Accepts a pointer to the first element of a 2d array.
void f2( size_t n, size_t m, int (*p)[ m ] ) {
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
         printf( "%s%3d", j ? " " : "", p[ i ][ j ] );
      }

      print( "\n" );
   }
}

int a2[ n ][ m ];
f2( n, m, a2 );
/* ---- or ---- */
int (*p2)[ m ] = malloc( sizeof( int ) * n * m );
f2( n, m, p2 );

You can also pass a pointer to the array itself, but it's a little more complicated.
// Accepts a pointer to a 2d array.
void f3( size_t n, size_t m, int (*p)[ n ][ m ] ) { 
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j ) {
         printf( "%s%3d", j ? " " : "", (*p)[ i ][ j ] );
      }

      print( "\n" );
   }
}

int a3[ n ][ m ];
f3( n, m, &a3 );
/* ---- or ---- */
int (*p3)[ n ][ m ] = malloc( sizeof( int ) * n * m );
f3( n, m, p3 );


Note that your previous question did not use a 2d or 1d array of int objects. It used an array of pointers to arrays, which uses a lot more memory, but it allows the rows to have different lengths.

In the C language as invented by Dennis Ritchie, given a declaration like:
int arr[5][3];

the syntax arr[i][j] would multiply i by the number of columns (3), add j, multiply by the size of each element (sizeof (int)), displace the starting address of the array by that number of bytes, and access an int at the resulting address, in a manner essentially agnostic as to whether i or j, individually, were within the respective array bounds.  Accessing arr[0][5] was equivalent to accessing arr[1][2].
The C Standard, however, only requires implementations to behave in that fashion when each and every individual subscript is within bounds.  Although some compilers are designed to always behave in a manner agnostic to individual array bounds, and gcc seems to behave in that fashion if code is written using explicit pointer-arithmetic syntax, the design of gcc seeks to produce the most efficient code to handle correctly inputs that would not cause any out-of-bounds array accesses using bracket operators, without regard for what might happen with other inputs.  Given something like:
unsigned char arr[5][3];

int sum_rows_v2(int n)
{
    int total=0;
    n*=3;
    total=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        total += arr[0][i];
    return total;
}

int arr2[4];
void test(int n)
{
    sum_rows_v2(n);
    if (n < 3)
        arr2[n] = 1;
}   

at optimization level 2 or higher, gcc will recognize that because the Standard would impose no requirements on the program's behavior if n exceeds 1, it replace the code for test() with simpler code equivalent to:
void test2(int n)
{
  arr2[n] = 1;
}

which will work correctly for all cases where n is 1 or less.
The Standard is unclear about what a program would need to do to receive a character pointer that could be used to access all of the bytes within arr, but writing the array access as *(arr[0]+i) seems to prevent the memory-corrupting "optimization" despite the fact that the latter expression is in fact the definition of the form using brackets.


When should I use one or the other, or are they equivalent ?

"element address using pointers arr+i" This will utilize pointer arithmetic, meaning that the compiler automatically looks up the element type of arr and then accesses address sizeof(item_type) * i.
"Element address = base address + element size * element number" This assumes that you are dealing with bytes/character type, since you are doing the previously mentioned calculation manually here.
To answer your question, you should use neither. You should always use the form arr[i], which is the most readable and which tends to avoid bugs related to pointer arithmetic. It is defined to be 100% equivalent to the corresponding pointer arithmetic *(arr + i).
Or if we want the address of the element, &arr[i].

int a[12];
int b[3][4];

After the code above has been compiled, there is no important difference between these two arrays.  The only difference is the syntax you use to access the elements in the C code.  In the case of the two-dimensional array, the compiler's type checker knows more about the structure of your data so it might prevent you from writing some buggy code or provide useful warnings when you overflow one of the smaller arrays.  Either way is OK.

GCC will sometimes process that attempts to read b[0][i] in a manner that may arbitrarily corrupt storage if a program would receive inputs that would cause i to exceed 3.

One difference, not a concern to the OP (yet), would be compile-time initialisation of arbitrary values for b[0][0], b[1][0] and b[2][0]. wanting the other 9 elements to take on the value 0... Using the int a[] version shown here couldn't take advantage of compiler's promise to set unspecified elements to 0...
